# Contact.MailingAddress

Tags: visualforce, formula-field, fields

I have to use the Contact Object's Mailing address in my code. But I am not able to use it in my visual force email templates or formula fields. Please suggest how can this field be used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MailingAddress` is a special field on the contact - it's a group of multiple fields. Instead you need to use `MailingStreet`, `MailingCity`, `MailingState`, `MailingPostcode` and `MailingCountry`. All these fields together form the `MailingAddress` field.

Answer (score 0):

It appears MailingPostCode should be MailingPostalCode.